# What does "salad days" mean, and when was it coined?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

What does *salad days* mean? I've heard the term used to describe past better days, but what does that have to do with salad?

Also, when was the phrase coined?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It refers to the time of youth when one was naive and inexperienced, and therefore happy and optimistic - in other words, when one was "green," as in "unripe" or "not yet mature." It's a bit of a convoluted pun.

Like so many English idioms, the term was coined by Shakespeare in the 17th century (Antony and Cleopatra.)

Comment: Shakespeare make a pun?? Say it ain't so!! :-D

Comment: If one equated life as a multi-course meal, the salad course comes early if not first.

Comment: @curt: the position of the salad course in a meal varies among European countries, and has changed over time as well… So that might or might not be an extra layer of cleverness in Shakespeare’s pun.

Comment: Salad course? The best way to enjoy a vegetarian diet is to feed it to the cow.

Answer (score 9):

Just agreeing with @PyroTyger, with [the actual quote](http://www.enotes.com/antony-and-cleopatra-text/act-scene-5#saladdays):

> Charmian: By your most gracious
>   pardon, I sing but after you.
>
> Cleopatra: My **salad days**, When I was
>   green in judgment, cold in blood, To
>   say as I said then!

Answer (score -2):

It also implies that, being young, you're also poor and cannot afford meat but eat salad. These days you can refer them as,
 "Ramen Days".